# sql query to extract data from xml

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm having issues querying the xml data stored in sql 2012.. below is the node tree i want to extract 'LicensingWindowStart' value.

```
 <sol>
    <so>
      <v>0</v>
      <t>BusinessMetadata</t>
      <al>
        <a k="Price">
          <v>4.99</v>
        </a>
        <a k="Currency">
          <v>US</v>
        </a>
      </al>
      <sol />
    </so>
    <so>
      <v>0</v>
      <t>RightsMetadata</t>
      <al>
        <a k="LicensingWindowStart">
          <v>2008-09-12T00:00:00</v>
        </a>
        <a k="LicensingWindowEnd">
          <v>2015-09-19T23:59:59</v>
        </a>
        <a k="AvailabilityWindowStart">
          <v>2008-09-12T00:00:00</v>
        </a>
        <a k="AvailabilityWindowEnd">
          <v>2015-09-19T23:59:59</v>
        </a>
        <a k="NewReleaseWindow">
          <v>0</v>
        </a>
        <a k="MaximumViewingLimit">
          <v>10080</v>
        </a>
      </al>
      <sol />
    </so>
    <so xsi:type="ListingsItem">
      <v>0</v>
      <id>test/1080i25spts3NascarSchool3mints_feature</id>
      <t>feature</t>
      <n>Nascar_Racing_School_feature</n>
      <fl>
        <f>HD</f>
      </fl>
      <al>
        <a k="AssetId">
          <v>1080i25spts3NascarSchool3mints_feature</v>
        </a>
        <a k="StreamFormat">
          <v>rtp</v>
        </a>
        <a k="RuntimeSeconds">
          <v>175</v>
        </a>
        <a k="DefaultLanguage">
          <v>en</v>
        </a>
        <a k="Content">
          <v t="FileName">1080i25-spts-3-NascarSchool-3min.ts</v>
          <v t="SizeInBytes" />
          <v t="NetworkType" />
          <v t="KBPS" />
          <v t="PlayReady" />
          <v t="WebInitiatorUrl" />
          <v t="LicenseServerProxyUrl" />
          <v t="Type" />
          <v t="PitchedFilename">1080i25-spts-3-NascarSchool-3min.ts</v>
        </a>
        <a k="ProcessContent">
          <v t="SourceFilePath">1080i25-spts-3-NascarSchool-3min.ts</v>
          <v t="DestinationDirectory">Media/e9959908-dabc-4691-a190-a30668d5c797</v>
          <v t="HD">true</v>
          <v t="HDCPDisable">false</v>
          <v t="Status">true</v>
          <v t="ServiceInformationID">e9959908-dabc-4691-a190-a30668d5c797</v>
          <v t="AssetType">feature</v>
          <v t="StreamFormat">rtp</v>
        </a>
      </al>
      <sol />
      <rl>
        <r>MPAA,R</r>
      </rl>
    </so>
    <so xsi:type="ListingsItem">
      <v>0</v>
      <id>test/1080i25spts3NascarSchool3mintsposter</id>
      <t>poster</t>
      <n>Nascar_Racing_School_poster</n>
      <fl>
        <f>SD</f>
      </fl>
      <al>
        <a k="AssetId">
          <v>1080i25spts3NascarSchool3mintsposter</v>
        </a>
        <a k="DefaultLanguage">
          <v>en</v>
        </a>
        <a k="Content">
          <v t="FileName">nascarschool_new.jpg</v>
          <v t="SizeInBytes" />
          <v t="NetworkType" />
          <v t="KBPS" />
          <v t="PlayReady" />
          <v t="WebInitiatorUrl" />
          <v t="LicenseServerProxyUrl" />
          <v t="Type" />
          <v t="PitchedFilename">nascarschool_new.jpg</v>
        </a>
        <a k="OrigFileLoc">
          <v>147\106\test-HD30002\Poster\nascarschool_new.jpg</v>
        </a>
        <a k="PosterUrl">
          <v>/posters/147/106/test-HD30002/Poster/nascarschool_new__{0}.jpg</v>
        </a>
      </al>
      <sol />
      <rl>
        <r>MPAA,R</r>
      </rl>
    </so>
  </sol>
```

I am using the below query:
(convert(xml, [columnname])).query('/SO/SOL/AL/LicensingWindowStart/V/text()') LicenseStartDate

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: ? Any common on the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

I go this example to work... you'd likely have to modify it to extract the value from a table column, or whatever it is you really want or need to do:

```
    DECLARE @xml xml;
    SET @xml = '
    <so>
      <v>0</v>
      <t>RightsMetadata</t>
      <al>
        <a k="LicensingWindowStart">
          <v>2014-09-12T00:00:00</v>
        </a>
      </al>
      <sol />
    </so>'

    SELECT CONVERT(datetime, 
               CONVERT(nvarchar(1000), 
                   @xml.query('(/so/al/a[@k=''LicensingWindowStart''])/v/text()')
               )
           ) AS LicensingWindowStart;
```

The first two statements (DECLARE and SET) just set up the test data.

The SELECT queries the xml variable to find the appropriate node, and then converts that value to a datetime.  Since direct xml-to-datetime conversions aren't allowed, I converted to an nvarchar(1000) first, and then converted THAT to a datetime.  The result is selected.

Since I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do (you didn't provide any schema or other information for context), I hope this is enough to help you find the right direction in solving your problem.

Returning back to your example above, I created a physical table with a non-xml column that contained xml as a string (not the best practice), and came up with this test for you:

```
    CREATE TABLE TextXmlTable (ColumnName nvarchar(1000));
    INSERT INTO TextXmlTable (ColumnName)
    VALUES ('
<sol>
    <so>
        <v>0</v>
        <t>BusinessMetadata</t>
        <al>
            <a k="Price">
                <v>4.99</v>
            </a>
            <a k="Currency">
                <v>US</v>
            </a>
        </al>
        <sol />
    </so>
    <so>
        <v>0</v>
        <t>RightsMetadata</t>
        <al>
            <a k="LicensingWindowStart">
                <v>2008-09-12T00:00:00</v>
            </a>
            <a k="LicensingWindowEnd">
                <v>2015-09-19T23:59:59</v>
            </a>
            <a k="AvailabilityWindowStart">
                <v>2008-09-12T00:00:00</v>
            </a>
            <a k="AvailabilityWindowEnd">
                <v>2015-09-19T23:59:59</v>
            </a>
            <a k="NewReleaseWindow">
                <v>0</v>
            </a>
            <a k="MaximumViewingLimit">
                <v>10080</v>
            </a>
        </al>
        <sol />
    </so>
    <so type="ListingsItem">
        <v>0</v>
        <id>test/1080i25spts3NascarSchool3mints_feature</id>
        <t>feature</t>
        <n>Nascar_Racing_School_feature</n>
        <fl>
            <f>HD</f>
        </fl>
        <al>
            <a k="AssetId">
                <v>1080i25spts3NascarSchool3mints_feature</v>
            </a>
            <a k="StreamFormat">
                <v>rtp</v>
            </a>
            <a k="RuntimeSeconds">
                <v>175</v>
            </a>
            <a k="DefaultLanguage">
                <v>en</v>
            </a>
            <a k="Content">
                <v t="FileName">1080i25-spts-3-NascarSchool-3min.ts</v>
                <v t="SizeInBytes" />
                <v t="NetworkType" />
                <v t="KBPS" />
                <v t="PlayReady" />
                <v t="WebInitiatorUrl" />
                <v t="LicenseServerProxyUrl" />
                <v t="Type" />
                <v t="PitchedFilename">1080i25-spts-3-NascarSchool-3min.ts</v>
            </a>
            <a k="ProcessContent">
                <v t="SourceFilePath">1080i25-spts-3-NascarSchool-3min.ts</v>
                <v t="DestinationDirectory">Media/e9959908-dabc-4691-a190-a30668d5c797</v>
                <v t="HD">true</v>
                <v t="HDCPDisable">false</v>
                <v t="Status">true</v>
                <v t="ServiceInformationID">e9959908-dabc-4691-a190-a30668d5c797</v>
                <v t="AssetType">feature</v>
                <v t="StreamFormat">rtp</v>
            </a>
        </al>
        <sol />
        <rl>
            <r>MPAA,R</r>
        </rl>
    </so>
    <so type="ListingsItem">
        <v>0</v>
        <id>test/1080i25spts3NascarSchool3mintsposter</id>
        <t>poster</t>
        <n>Nascar_Racing_School_poster</n>
        <fl>
            <f>SD</f>
        </fl>
        <al>
            <a k="AssetId">
                <v>1080i25spts3NascarSchool3mintsposter</v>
            </a>
            <a k="DefaultLanguage">
                <v>en</v>
            </a>
            <a k="Content">
                <v t="FileName">nascarschool_new.jpg</v>
                <v t="SizeInBytes" />
                <v t="NetworkType" />
                <v t="KBPS" />
                <v t="PlayReady" />
                <v t="WebInitiatorUrl" />
                <v t="LicenseServerProxyUrl" />
                <v t="Type" />
                <v t="PitchedFilename">nascarschool_new.jpg</v>
            </a>
            <a k="OrigFileLoc">
                <v>147\106\test-HD30002\Poster\nascarschool_new.jpg</v>
            </a>
            <a k="PosterUrl">
                <v>/posters/147/106/test-HD30002/Poster/nascarschool_new__{0}.jpg</v>
            </a>
        </al>
        <sol />
        <rl>
            <r>MPAA,R</r>
        </rl>
    </so>
</sol>'
    );

    SELECT CONVERT(datetime, 
               CONVERT(nvarchar(1000), 
                   (CONVERT(xml, [ColumnName])).query('(sol/so/al/a[@k=''LicensingWindowStart''])/v/text()')
               )
           ) AS LicensingWindowStart
    FROM TextXmlTable;
```

It seems your biggest issue was trying to include the "SOL" node in your query for some reason...

Comment: I probably might need to add the whole xml to be more clear.. with your query i am just getting the output as '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' for all columns.

Comment: Okay, I edited based on your updated XML... I had to put the "SOL" back in, and I was having issues with the "<so xsi:type="ListingsItem">" on line 40, giving me a parse error with "undefined prefix", so I removed the xsi just for this example.  You'll still need to deal with that in your code (presumably the prefix is defined elsewhere outside the example you provided).  I hope this helps.

Comment: ...are you still having issues?  Did you resolve your problem?  Did this answer help at all?